# LED current while off

Tags: led, current, light, low-power

I have a vague recollection that while off, a LED can actually receive light and generate a small current (in uA).
Is that correct? How does that work? What is the best way to prevent this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A LED can work as a (not very good) photodiode, and produce a small current when it receives light. You have to connect it like a photodiode, though, that is reversed polarised. In a normal circuit you won't have trouble with it.

Comment: Yes, and in principle, any reverse-biased PN junction is sensitive to light. The more fossilised of us will remember the OC71 germanium transistor which was encapsulated in a small glass envelope painted black. The manufacturers (Mullard) then produced the OCP71 phototransistor in a clear glass envelope which was much more expensive. Enterprising hackers soon realised that you could just scrape the paint off an OC71 and get a phototransistor with identical performance.

Comment: Mullard got wise to that, and painted the inside of the glass!

Comment: Why did they use glass? Cheapest to seal?

Comment: Does this mean that a LED technically consumes slightly less current when turned on in a very bright environment compared to a dark one? :-)

Comment: I have an LED in a very low power application, and I am afraid that this LED might drain a few microamperes from the battery. Would that be possible or realistic?

Comment: Forest Mims used colored LED's specifically to get wavelength-matched photodetection of the sun. http://www.opticsinfobase.org/abstract.cfm?URI=ao-31-33-6965

Comment: @Gauthier - as said in my answer, the LED has to be reverse polarised, i.e. cathode voltage higher than anode. In a normal LED driving circuit leakage current is determined by the switching transistor. (Sorry for the late answer)